# Получить день недели и число в date-fns?

Tags: javascript

хочу получить с помощью **date-fns** завтрашний и послезавтрашний день в таком формате "День недели, день месяц". Например: "Вторник, 6 июля", "Среда, 7 июля"

```
import { format } from 'date-fns'

const date = Date.now();
const day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const tomorrow = new Date(date + day);
const dayAfterTomorrow = new Date(date + day * 2);

const tomorrowString = format(tomorrow, 'dd.MM.yyyy')
const dayAfterTomorrowString = format(dayAfterTomorrow, 'dd.MM.yyyy')
```

Знаю как получит завтрашний и послезавтрашний дни, а как с помощью **date-fns** получить нужный формат не знаю

Comment: https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/format прочитать документацию?

Comment: И если уж использовать библиотеку, то логичнее и манипуляции со временем проводить ей же https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/add
А то из-за перевода часов ваше вычисление «завтра» может врать в любую сторону.